# Import error on oursql

Tags: python, windows, cython, oursql

Im trying to set up some programs to work on a website with cherrypy framework on my laptop. Now i need oursql for the website. I used for both Cython and OurSQL executables. I found a site with executables from the cython download site ("Christoph Gohlke has created Windows installers available for download on his site." [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cython)) I both downloaded the versions for windows (I have Windows 7 64-bit) and Python 2.7. After this installation i try to run my script for starting the website and I got the following error:

```
    import oursql
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I searched the internet, but I didn't manage to find a solution. Anybody has an idea how this can occur and maybe how this can be fixed?

Comment: Those binaries are linked against the official MySQL 5.1 distribution and depend on `libmysql.dll`, which is not redistributed with the oursql installers. Install MySQL 5.1 (64 bit if you are using 64 bit Python) and make sure `libmysql.dll` is found in os.path.

Comment: Got rid of the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment of choglke was the answer